# How to manually geocode records or see a reference list of countries CartoDB recognizes?

Tags: carto, geocoding

I'm making [a quick choropleth](https://tkb.cartodb.com/viz/2aa27e54-202c-11e5-b358-0e0c41326911/public_map) map that classifies countries by income level.

The in-built geocoder works mostly fine on the country names (there are also 3 letter codes in the dataset) but there are 8 or so areas that it hasn't geocoded and assigned a polygon to, for example "Isle of Man", "Andorra", "Kosovo" and "East Timor".

Is there a way for me to manually geocode these or to see what reference list of countries CartoDB is using so that I might tweak the dataset to get the geocoder to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO3 and ISO2 codes should work always for the countries.

I have done a test with the four regions that you added and all of them seem to be working correctly for me --  you can check the table [here](https://team.cartodb.com/u/iriberri/tables/untitled_table_372).

In order to geocode it, I used the "administrative regions" option, with "description" in the first selector, leaving the second one empty.

Do you have any special characters in the cells besides the names? as empty spaces or line feeds? Perhaps they're not being sanitized correctly in the CartoDB end.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This still doesn't seem to work for me, when I use the admin regions geocoding as you do, I get the error "No rows were georeferenced It seems that some of your rows didn't finish successfully. Perhaps these rows contained empty values or perhaps we just didn't know what the values meant. We encourage you to take a look and try again."  The only difference I notice with your version is that in mine the "the_geom" column contains "GeoJSON" types and mine has "polygon" types. I imported the table from a CSV if that makes any difference?

Comment: OK, got it to work by manually creating a separate table with countries that wouldn't initially geocode, geocoding them and merging the table back with the original.

Comment: GeoJSON is what is shown in the public page, but my geometries are Polygons too :) if you want us to look into this deeper, you can send us your username to support@cartodb.com so that we could check why it failed!